# Setup Cloud Function to trigger Cloud Composer DAG in Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-functions, terraform, google-cloud-composer, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a cloud composer environment:

```
resource "google_composer_environment" "default" {
  name   = "default"
  region = "us-central1"
  config {
    node_count = 5

    node_config {
      zone         = "us-central1-a"
      machine_type = "n1-standard-2"
    }
  }
}
```

and a cloud function that I use to trigger that environment

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "trigger_dag" {
  name    = "trigger_dag"
  runtime = "python37"
  labels = {
    "deployment-tool" = "terraform"
  }

  event_trigger {
    event_type = "google.pubsub.topic.publish"
    resource = "projects/${var.project_id}/topics/trigger_dag"
  }

  entry_point = "trigger_dag"
  environment_variables = {
    "AIRFLOW_URI" = google_composer_environment.default.config.0.airflow_uri
  }

  source_repository {
    url = local.repo_url
  }

  timeouts {}

  depends_on = [google_composer_environment.default]
}
```

However, I also need to give the cloud function an IAP client id to use when calling the DAG: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf#getting_the_client_id

Is there a way, in Terraform, to run the python script to generate the client id whenever the DAG is recreated (so the webserver changes and the old id is not valid), and set that id as an environment variable on the cloud function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We got it to work using an [external data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source) to run the python script and return the client id.

```
data "external" "composer_iap_client_id" {
  program = ["python", "${path.module}/iap_client.py"]

  query = {
    airflow_uri = google_composer_environment.default.config.0.airflow_uri
  }
}
```

iap_client.py

```py
import json
import sys
import urllib.parse

import requests


def get_iap_client_id(airflow_uri: str) -> str:
    redirect_response = requests.get(airflow_uri, allow_redirects=False)
    redirect_location = redirect_response.headers['location']

    # Extract the client_id query parameter from the redirect.
    parsed = urllib.parse.urlparse(redirect_location)
    query_string = urllib.parse.parse_qs(parsed.query)
    return query_string['client_id'][0]


def main() -> None:
    json_input = json.load(sys.stdin)
    client_id = get_iap_client_id(json_input['airflow_uri'])
    json.dump({'iap_client_id': client_id}, sys.stdout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

updated the cloud function to pull the iap client id as an environment variable:

```
  ...
  environment_variables = {
    "AIRFLOW_URI" = google_composer_environment.default.config.0.airflow_uri
    "IAP_CLIENT_ID" = data.external.composer_iap_client_id.result.iap_client_id
  }
  ...
```